# .NET 6 Razor Pages SEO Friendly URL

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to create SEO friendly URL's using .NET 6 and Razor Pages (not MVC). From a razor page view:

```
<a asp-page="/Post" asp-route-id="9">Test Link</a>
```

I link to a corresponding page handler:

```
[BindProperty]
public PostViewModel? Post { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)
{
    Post = new PostViewModel();
    Post = await _postService.GetPostAsync(id);

    return Page();
}
```

The page handler will fetch the post by the `id` parameter. In the page model `PostViewModel` there are properties for `Category`, `Topic`, and `UrlTitle`. I would like to use these properties to generate an SEO friendly URL, like:

```
https:/wwww.mysite.com/post/{id}/{category}/{topic}/{urltitle}
```

I'm not sure how to get these property values to the URL?

Answer (score 1):

In Asp.net core Razor page, to set the Friendly URLs, we could override routes template via the `@page` directive in the .cshtml page, like this:

```
@page "/Post/{id?}/{category?}/{topic?}/{urlTitle?}"
```

Or, we can configure the razor page convention like this:

```
builder.Services
    .AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Post", "Post/{id?}/{category?}/{topic?}/{urlTitle?}");
    });
```

> The first time the method is hit, just the id exists. It then
> populates the view model, but when it hits the method the second time,
> only the id, category, topic & urltitle properties are populated but
> the rest are empty?

After that, in the Index page, you can use the following hyperlink to access the Get handler:

```
@*href ="/Post/9"*@
<a asp-page="/Post" asp-route-id="9">Test Link</a>

@*href ="/Post/9/C1/T1/U1"*@
<a asp-page="/Post" asp-route-id="9" asp-route-category="C1" asp-route-topic="T1" asp-route-urltitle="U1">Test Link</a>
```

For the category, topic or urltitle parameters, if you want to edit them using textbox, you can use JavaScript to build the request url based on the parameters. code like this:

```
@page "/Post/{id?}/{category?}/{topic?}/{urlTitle?}"
@model RazorWebApp.Pages.PostModel
@*<a asp-page="/Post" asp-route-id="9">Test Link</a>*@

<h2>Test Post page</h2>


<form method="get" asp-route-id="@Model?.Post?.Id">
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" id="txtId" asp-for="Post.Id" />
        Category: <input type="text" id="txtcategory" asp-for="Post.Category"  />
        Topic: <input type="text" id="txttopic" asp-for="Post.Topic"  />
        Url Title: <input type="text" id="txturltitle" asp-for="Post.UrlTitle"/>

        <input type="submit" value="Test Link (Submit Button)" />


        <a asp-page="/Post" asp-route-id="@Model?.Post?.Id" 
        asp-route-category="@Model?.Post?.Category" 
        asp-route-topic="@Model?.Post?.Topic" 
        asp-route-urltitle="@Model?.Post?.UrlTitle"
        onclick="return HyperLinkClick(this);"
        >Test Link (Hyperlink)</a>
    </p>
</form>

@section Scripts{
   <script>
        function HyperLinkClick(e) {
           event.preventDefault();
            var id = document.getElementById("txtId").value === "" ? "null" : parseInt(document.getElementById("txtId").value);
            var category = document.getElementById("txtcategory").value === "" ? "null" : document.getElementById("txtcategory").value;
            var topic = document.getElementById("txttopic").value === "" ? "null" : document.getElementById("txttopic").value;
            var urltitle = document.getElementById("txturltitle").value === "" ? "null" : document.getElementById("txturltitle").value;

            if (category != "null" && topic != "null" && urltitle != "null"){ 
                window.location.href = "/Post/"+ id + "/" + category + "/" + topic + "/" + urltitle;
            }
       }
   </script> 
}
```

The result as below:

[image]

**Update**

> The category, topic and urltitle values are stored in a database not
> as user input forms

In this scenario, you can modify the Post page code as below:

```
public class PostModel : PageModel
{
    //[BindProperty]
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public PostViewModel? Post { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)
    {

        //find the post based on the id.
        if (id==9)
        {
            //Post = await _postService.GetPostAsync(id);
            Post = new PostViewModel() { 
                Id = id, Category="C1", 
                Topic="T1", UrlTitle="U1" };
        }

        return Page();
    }
}
```

Post.cshtml page:

```
@page "/Post/{id?}/{category?}/{topic?}/{urlTitle?}"
@model RazorWebApp.Pages.PostModel
@*<a asp-page="/Post" asp-route-id="9">Test Link</a>*@

<h2>Test Post page</h2>

<a asp-page="/Post" asp-route-id="@Model?.Post?.Id"
   asp-route-category="@Model?.Post?.Category"
   asp-route-topic="@Model?.Post?.Topic"
   asp-route-urltitle="@Model?.Post?.UrlTitle"
   onclick="return HyperLinkClick(this);">Test Link (Hyperlink)</a>
```

Then, the result as below: please pay attention to the url of the hyperlink in the lower-left corner.

[image]

Comment: The category, topic and urltitle values are stored in a database not as user input forms.

Comment: Hi @PixelPaul, check the update in the above reply. You could directly bind [the `asp-route-{value}` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asp-route-value) using the Page Model. After that you can check the hyperlink `href` attribute, the url is a friendly url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

In a Razor Page View:

```
<a asp-page="/Post" asp-route-id="@Post.Id" asp-route-category="@Post.Category" asp-route-topic="@Post.Topic" asp-route-urltitle="@Post.UrlTitle">Test Link</a>
```

Update the `OnGetAsync` method to accept these additional route parameters:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id, string category, string topic, string urltitle)
{
    Post = new PostViewModel();
    Post = await _postService.GetPostAsync(id);

    if (category != Post.Category || topic != Post.Topic || urltitle != Post.UrlTitle)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Page();
}
```

And go to the `Configure` method of the `Startup` class using the `endpoints.MapRazorPages` method:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "post",
        pattern: "/post/{id}/{category}/{topic}/{urltitle}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Post", action = "Index" }
    );
});
```

Here, the `pattern` parameter specifies the URL pattern to match, and the `defaults` parameter specifies the default controller and action to use for this route. You will also need to create a corresponding `PostController` with an `Index` action to handle the request.

Comment: Why would I need to create a PostController? What would that controller do that the OnGetAsync page handler shown above doesn't do?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your **post** page (`.cshtml` file) add:

```
@page "{id}/{category}/{topic}/{urltitle}"
```

In your **home** page model (`.cshtml.cs` file) add:

```cs
public List<PostViewModel> Posts { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    Posts = await _postService.GetPostsAsync();

    return Page();
}
```

and then in your **home** page create the links using:

```
@foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
{
    <a asp-page="/Post"
       asp-route-id="@post.Id"
       asp-route-category="@post.Category"
       asp-route-topic="@post.Topic"
       asp-route-urltitle="@post.UrlTitle">@post.Description</a>
}
```

Check [Route Templates](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#route-templates)

Comment: Let's say I want to have a link to post id = 9 on the home page. The parameters for Model.Post.Category, Model.Post.Topic and Model.Post.UrlTitle would not be part of the page model for the home page?

Comment: Do you want your home page to link to post page and then the post page to fill the rest of the route parameters based on the id?

Comment: Something like redirecting `/post/{id}` to `/post/{id}/{category}/{topic}/{urltitle}`?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was thinking. The post page would fill the route parameters based on the id.

Comment: The first time the method is hit, just the id exists. It then populates the view model, but when it hits the method the second time, only the id, category, topic & urltitle properties are populated but the rest are empty?

Comment: Then I guess you have to call `Post = await _postService.GetPostAsync(id);` second time before `return Page();`

Comment: A second database call seems really inefficient.

Comment: Then do the query in your home page to get the list of posts and create the links like I suggested initially.